# Exce VBA - Fetch links from a fetching-builds website

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, fetch

I've been trying to fetch the data from "http://builds.reicast.com/" but the issue is the website is also fetching information (which is what I actually need; the Master dev-build URLs). I feel like the delay in loading the Javascript fetching is hindering the fetching process on my side. Also, I've tried several different ways of fetching the build-URL's but they never appear (I'm assuming it's the same issue as mentioned previously).

This is what it looks like:

```
Sub FetchData()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://builds.reicast.com/", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "master"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: printscreen]

How can I get it to load the "master dev-builds section"?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Internet Explorer Controls Library added via VBE > Tools > References and include a timed loop to ensure links are present e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, commits As Object, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://builds.reicast.com/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            Set commits = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".commit [href]")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While commits.Length = 0

        Debug.Print commits.Length
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To commits.Length - 1
            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(i + 1, 1) = commits.item(i).innerText
                .Cells(i + 1, 2) = commits.item(i).getAttribute("href")
            End With
        Next
        Stop '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you want to write out the whole table:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, hTable As Object, t As Date, headers(), ws As Worksheet
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    headers = Array("Commit", "Date", "Android", "Win_x86", "Win_x64")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://builds.reicast.com/"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set hTable = ie.document.querySelector("#builds table")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While hTable Is Nothing
        Writetable hTable, 1, ws
        ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Writetable(ByVal hTable As Object, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Dim tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        If r > 2 Then
            For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                Select Case c
                Case 1, 3, 4, 5
                    ws.Cells(r - 1, c) = td.FirstChild
                Case Else
                    ws.Cells(r - 1, c) = td.innerText
                End Select
                c = c + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Example output:**

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is perfect :) Thank you soo much!

Comment: On a side-note, if it's possible, how could I limit it to the first 10 entries?

Comment: exit when r = 11  or simply:  If r > 2 And r < 11 Then ... https://pastebin.com/p957z6uC

Comment: or r> 2 And r < 13 as already excluding first two rows. You get the idea. https://pastebin.com/SDi0WRxc

Comment: One last question I've managed to get it to work on other websites but "https://www.pj64-emu.com/nightly-builds" doesn't have an "id" I can tag for documentation. Excluding the header edits and other stuff, how you you re-write the ie.document.querySelector.. for it to read that table?? I'm sorry for taking on more questions :/

Comment: No worries. It is not a table per se. You can grab the parent  div with querySelector(“.div-table”) but with correct “” not the ones from using mobile. You can loop the divs with class div-table-row and differentiate the columns within each row by their repetitive class names. There are a few different ways to approach this and I would probably play around til I found one I thought was efficient and clean looking. If you get stuck post a question and drop a link here.

Comment: I managed to get around the previous ones, but a greater challenge has risen I've spent quite a lot of time tinkering away unsuccessfully, if you have a moment, could you take a stab at this one "https://ci.appveyor.com/project/exjam/decaf-emu/build/artifacts". It seems pretty straightforward but the href is nested within elements of the page that I just can't get its complet url in a dynamic way.. I have to find a way to dynamically get the url of "decaf-build.zip" and copy/pasting wouldn't work as the download-ref-link could change at anytime :/ Thanks a lot for your help :)